# 1+1D conformal field theory for the critical point of non-Abelian symmetry breaking

Tags: group-theory, conformal-field-theory, symmetry-breaking

In 1+1D, a spontaneous symmetry breaking of a finite group $G$ gives rise to critical point. What is the CFT for such a critical point.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but I'm interested. Is the question only meant to include cases where $G$ is completely broken, with no unbroken subgroup? And could there be cases where $G$ is broken in stages, with one phase transition that leaves an unbroken subgroup $H\subset G$ and then another separate phase transition that breaks $H$? That would seem to give two or more associated CFTs, one per phase transition, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Yes, I assume $G$ is completely broken, to be concrete. Other general cases are also interesting.