# Can a finite simple symmetry group be spontaneously broken in stages, with multiple phase transitions?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, group-theory, phase-transition, symmetry-breaking

Can a finite simple symmetry group $G$ be spontaneously broken in stages, with two or more phase transitions, each one leaving a successively smaller unbroken subgroup?

By simple, I mean no normal subgroups. This excludes product groups, which clearly can be broken in stages.

I'm especially interested in the case of $1+1$-dimensional spacetime, because this question came to mind while thinking about another recent question: [1+1D conformal field theory for the critical point of non-Abelian symmetry breaking](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/571612)